# Calling stored procedure using value from second stored procedure to produce single result?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I have decided to educate myself on stored procedures in MySQL, but with the syntax being quite different from my usual stomping ground (php/javascript), I was hoping to determine if my understanding of the capabilities of these procedures is correct, and if so, how I achieve what I am after.

Currently, I am have two tables, 'people' and 'posts', as follows:

```
people
person_id INT(10)
first_name VARCHAR(32)
last_name VARCHAR(64)

posts
post_id INT(10)
author_id INT(10)
body_text TEXT
created DATETIME
```

From that, I created a simple all-purpose stored procedure, as follows:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE getPerson(IN person INT(10))
  BEGIN
    SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) as long_name, CONCAT(last_name, ', ', first_name) as index_name FROM people WHERE person_id = person;
  END //
DELIMITER ;
```

So far so good, but now here's where my understanding breaks down... I want to create a second procedure called 'getPost', which when passed a post_id, will return the post data from the respective row in the posts table, but also call the getPerson procedure on the author_id column, so that a single result returned will consist of the fields: `post_id, long_name, index_name, body_text, created`.

I've trial and errored for a couple of hours, and while I may have had the right approach at one point (use a join on the result of getPerson?), my sql syntax hasn't extended much beyond single-statment MySQL calls from PHP. My questions are:

1. Is this a common/reasonable approach to what I want to do or is there something better? (I don't want to use a scripting language)
2. If so, might someone share how to do this?
3. Am I correct to use a procedure for this kind of thing, or is a function as good/better?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create a view called **viewPeoplePosts** that combines **People and their Posts**. Then you can modify your stored proc to query the view. Let the **view do all the hard work** and let stored procedure simply return the result.